# Referencing an existing image in theme settings

Tags: 8, forms

In a custom theme (Drupal 8.4.3) I would like to add a theme setting, where I can reference (not upload) an image to use as a background image. Like in a normal reference field, already uploaded images should be choosable; these images are stored in media entities.
How can I build such a theme setting? I only found information about [Uploading images in theme settings](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142053/drupal-8-theme-header-background-image-upload).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to find an example of this, either, but here's a simple demo setting a reference to a media/image in theme settings (with the autocomplete widget):

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function THEME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
  // Work-around for a core bug affecting admin themes. See issue #943212.
  if (isset($form_id)) {
    return;
  }

  $opts = [
    '#type'          => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#title'         => t("Call to Action Background"),
    '#description'   => t("Default call to action background media image; may be overridden on individual elements."),
    '#target_type'   => 'media',
    '#selection_settings' => ['target_bundles' => ['image']],
  ];
  if ($default_id = theme_get_setting('call_to_action_background')) {
    // element stores an int ID, but default value has to be the loaded entity
    $image = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->load($default_id);
    $opts['#default_value'] = $image;
  }
  $form['call_to_action_background'] = $opts;

}
```

To retrieve and render, use a THEME_preprocess hook with parameter &$variables:

```
$media_id = theme_get_setting('call_to_action_background');
$media = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->load($media_id);
$variables['media_build'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('media')->view(‌​$media, 'some_media_display_mode');
```

The render array is then available in twig:

```
{{ media_build }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you also know how to retrieve the image in a function like THEME_preprocess_html()?

Comment: Well, can't get that to format. I'll update the answer above.